# Yii redirecting to a different view page after login

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I have a page called   "MyHome" which  should be viewed after a successful login.I have included this page under site folder .But it shows  the following error

```
Error 404
The system is unable to find the requested action "MyHome".
```

My code for the actionLogin of siteController

```
public function actionLogin()
{


    $model=new LoginForm;


    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }


    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];

        if($model->validate() && $model->login())

    //  $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        $this->redirect(array('/site/MyHome'));

    }

    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

My Code for the MyHome view page

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />

    <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/form.css" />

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" id="page">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></div>
    </div><!-- header -->

    <div id="mainmenu">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'All offers', 'url'=>array('/producerOffer/index'),'visible'=> Yii::app()->user->type==="consumer"),
                array('label'=>'My requirements', 'url'=>array('/consumerReq/view', array('id'=>Yii::app()->user->id)),'visible'=> Yii::app()->user->type==="consumer"),
                array('label'=>'All requirements', 'url'=>array('/ConsumerReq/index'),'visible'=> Yii::app()->user->type==="producer"),
                array('label'=>'My offers', 'url'=>array('/producerOffer/view',array('id'=>Yii::app()->user->id)), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),

            ),
        )); ?>
    </div><!-- mainmenu -->
    <?php if(isset($this->breadcrumbs)):?>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
            'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
        )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
    <?php endif?>

    <?php echo $content; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> by My Company.<br/>
        All Rights Reserved.<br/>
        <?php echo Yii::powered(); ?>
    </div><!-- footer -->

</div><!-- page -->

</body>
</html>
```

After a successful login this page must be rendered,Anybody help me how to resolve this issue, since I am a newbie

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the action defined in that controller? It seems like that error would come from not having the action defined. Try to define the actionMyHome method in the site controller.

```
public function actionMyHome() {
    $this->render('myHome',array());
}
```

Comment: No I have not defined that action in the siteController, how should I write the action since its a static page and not  rendering any data?can you please help me

Comment: I added it to the answer above. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: ya its directing to my home page but showing only the template, not all the links in the view code . can you tell me what should I do pls?

Comment: like its showing only one more template not the complete view page

Comment: So are you saying it's not showing the layout? I am not sure what you mean by it's not showing the complete view page? It will display whatever view you put in $this->render within the views/site directory. Are you calling a partial from within there? If so put echo $this->renderPartial

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the action that you are directing to.

In your login code, you have :

```
$this->redirect(array('/site/MyHome'));
```

This will redirect to a method actionMyHome() in the class SiteController.

Therefore, you need to create the missing class :

```
class SiteController extends Controller {

   public function actionMyHome() {
       echo 'I am still here';
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$this->redirect(array('/MyHome'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$this->redirect(array('site/MyHome'));
```

Comment: post your error and add your your site controller code also in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$url = Yii::app()->createUrl('site/MyHome');

Yii::app()-request->redirect($url);

OR

$this->redirect($url);
```

Also Check 'actionMyhome' function is available in 'SiteController'

Answer (score 0):

The `SiteController` as it is generated has a `page` action, which displays static pages. Using this feature you don't need to add new actions every time you add static content.

To redirect to a static page, place the code of the page in `protected/views/site/pages`, and use the `page` action in URLs:

```
$this->redirect(array('/site/page', 'view'=>'MyHome'));
```

Answer (score 0):

i think problem in webserver 
you use iis or apache or?
please test below code

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
   public function actionMyhome() {
       $this->render('myhome',array());
       }
    }
```

and change MyHome.php  to myhome.php file in view /site/MyHome.php

Answer (score -1):

It should be defined

```
public function accessRules()   {       return array(           array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('myhome'),
                'users'=>array('@'),            ),
                    );  }
```

Comment: Please Improve your answer code. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: is this enough @ankit

Comment: yes, a lot improved. see this [suggestion](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=php+codebeautifier&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN725IN725&oq=php+codebea&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.4464j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  for more improvement